# Primefaces refresh one panelgrid from other panelgrid

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Iam having a requirement where on selecting date present in one panel grid, the component present in other panel grid needs to be refreshed. I am able to refresh components in the same panel grid by "form:text" but the same is not applying for component in other panelgrid.

Can anyone help me how to update other panelgrids component

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<h:outputLabel for="popupCal2" value="To Date" rendered="#{leaveBean.showCalendarText}" />
<p:calendar value="#{leaveBean.toDate}" id="popupCal2" showOn="button" widgetVar="tdate" maxdate="#{leaveBean.maxDate}" mindate="#{leaveBean.minDate}"
rendered="#{leaveBean.showCalendar}" required="true" requiredMessage="TO Date Is Mandatory" readonlyInput="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{leaveController.getNoOfdays}" update="form1:showDays,form1:uploadFile></p:ajax>
</p:calendar>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<h:outputLabel id="showdays" for="uploadFile" value="Upload Document" rendered="#{leaveBean.showUploadText}" />
<p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" rendered="#{leaveBean.showUpload}" fileUploadListener="#{leaveController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
dragDropSupport="false" sizeLimit="102400"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Please post your code.....?

Comment: I am afraid , you'll have to post full xhtml code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put one output panel outside of that panel grid with id as "text" and you can call update="text".
 it will work for you.